# Show class diagram from all packages

Tags: class-diagram, enterprise-architect

I'm working with Enterprise Architect.
I would like to see simultaneously the class diagrams from all the packages in order to better visualize the relationships between classes.
Is it possible?

Comment: Do you mean you want to display several diagrams on scren at once rather than having to switch between them?

Comment: I mean, I have several packages with several classes in each. I can see all the class in the package A at the same time (and thus, I can see the relationships - association, aggregation, etc. - between these classes). But, I want to see all the classes of the package (package A, B, etc.) at the same time. Because I want to see the relationships between classes which come from different packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No such thing exists, as far as I know. Your options are to draw a new class diagram containing elements from the existing diagrams or create a package diagram which should describe the relationships between different packages. There is a reason for that - relationships between classes in different packages are on another level compared to inter-package relationships and normally they shouldn't be mixed.